# Lua: memory mapped file?

Tags: lua, memory-mapped-files

does any of you know how to create a memory mapped file in Lua?
I have a program that writes code in Lua. I now want to execute the code without saving it to file, but writing it to a "memory" file and then executing it from memory directly.
But I did not find a way to do this. I am now writing a file like this:

```
file:write(instruction..'\n')
```

then loading and running it as:

```
file = loadfile("filename")
file()
```

Does anyone know how to write the file to memory or to execute it from memory without saving it to disk?

Comment: Do you actually want a memory-mapped file (as with [mmap(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)), or merely a buffer that can be manipulated using the file interface as if it were a file?

Comment: I explain better my problem, maybe it was not described well

Answer (score 3):

Use loadstring:

```
chunk = loadstring("return ..., 1+2, 'hi'")
assert(chunk)
a, b, c = chunk(123) -- you can call many times
print (a,b,c) -- prints 123     3      hi
```

Comment: Thank you, tried that, but it is not as fast as loading the file and then running it as assert(file)() or just file()

Comment: I really doubt that, but I haven't tested. What method did you use to measure this? In any case, it is the only way to "execute it from memory without saving it to disk" (and note that a memory mapped file is a block of memory that is on the file system, available for multiple processes to share so it does not satisfy "without saving it to disk" :).

Comment: Thank you Scholli, actually your suggestion works well. I made a mistake before. Thank you!